# turn decision for robot in python issues

Tags: python, linux, ros, robotics

I am a college student and I have just started a ROS Programming project for NASA. I am currently trying to develop a program that finds the farthest distance on either side (not in front or behind) and go that direction.
"""

```
laserFull = rc.get_laser_full()
print(max(laserFull[200:400]))
```

"""

This is what I have so far but I cannot figure out how to find which way the max is and go that way.

Here is all my code thus far and I am using the construct sim website to program on

"""

```
from robot_control_class import RobotControl
rc = RobotControl(robot_name="Turtlebot")


laser = rc.get_front_laser()

def move():
    while laser > 1.5:
        rc.move_straight_time("forward", .5, 2)
        laser = rc.get_front_laser()
    laser = rc.get_front_laser()
    if laser <=1.5:    


def turnDecision():
    laserFull = rc.get_laser_full()  
    print(max(laserFull[200:400]))
    

def turnRight():
    rc.turn('counter-clockwise', .5, 3)
def turnLeft():
    rc.turn('clockwise', .5, 3)


laserFull = rc.get_laser_full()
print(max(laserFull[200:400]))
turn
```

"""